# Convert array of objects inside in object into array of properties

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an Object which is having some properties like this:

```
obj1={
    "id": 2,
    "description": "",
    "operationIds": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Standard"
        }
    ],
    "ratingIds": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "name1",
            "description": "",
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "name4",
            "description": "",
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "name8",
            "description": "",
        },
    ],
}
```

I want covert the array of objects (`operationIds` and `ratingIds`) inside the object to array of properties, I'm receiving this object and I want to apply the change on it and supply another method so it should look like this:

```
obj1={
    "id": 2,
    "description": "",
    "operationIds": [
        1
    ],
    "ratingIds": [
        1,
        4,
        8
    ],
    "timestamp": "AAAAAAAGJ6c=",
    "estimatedUtilReconciliationApplies": true
}
```

I was able to do it but in a verry ugly way, is there a more simple and clear way to accomplish this ?

```
let x = {...obj} as any;
let ar1 = x.operationIds;
const arr1= ar1.map(function (obj) {
  return obj.id;
});

let ar2 = x.ratingIds;
const arr2= ar2.map(function (obj) {
  return obj.id;
});

x.operatingEnvironmentIds = arr1;
x.thrustRatingIds = arr2;
```

Comment: What makes your approach "ugly"?

Comment: Your solution is perfectly fine.

Comment: forget about naming I'm just testing, but its long and I'm wondering if there is an easy and short solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use spread operator and map

```js
let obj1={
    "id": 2,
    "description": "",
    "operationIds": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Standard"
        }
    ],
    "ratingIds": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "name1",
            "description": "",
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "name4",
            "description": "",
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "name8",
            "description": "",
        },
    ],
}

console.log({
    ...obj1,
    operationIds:obj1.operationIds.map(elem => elem.id),
    ratingIds:obj1.ratingIds.map(elem => elem.id),
})
```

And as a function

```js
let obj1={
    "id": 2,
    "description": "",
    "operationIds": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Standard"
        }
    ],
    "ratingIds": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "name1",
            "description": "",
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "name4",
            "description": "",
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "name8",
            "description": "",
        },
    ],
}
let transform = (obj) => {
    return({
        ...obj,
        operationIds:obj.operationIds.map(elem => elem.id),
        ratingIds:obj.ratingIds.map(elem => elem.id),
    })
}
let transformed = transform(obj1)
console.log(transformed)
```

Answer (score 0):

We loop the array and use the Object.assign() method to convert an array of objects to a single object. This merges each object into a single resultant object.

The Object.assign() method also merges the properties of one or more objects into a single object.

Comment: Maybe you could make a concrete code example?